Creating a costmap using hector_slam
I have a map created using hector_slam but I don't know how to publish a 2d costmap to use in my navigation algortihm. I did my research and costmap_2d package seems to be the best option but I don't know how to use it with hector_slam. Any answers regarding creating a global costmap from a /map topic is appreciated.

I assumed that you are working in ROS 1.
After creating the map, a recommended way to do the navigation in ROS1 is by using move_base node. This node gives the "navigation path" to the robot by considering global and local costmap.
Take a look at his example of the navigation package with turtleBot here.
These global and local costmap are configured in the folder param at global_costmap_params.yaml, local_costmap_params.yaml, and costmap_common_params.yaml.
To visualize the costmap, you can use RViz.

Yes I use ROS1, I forgot to mention it. Thanks for the answer but I don't want a navigation path, since I will be using my own navigation algorithm after creating a costmap. Is there a way I can simply create a costmap using the map created with SLAM?

Have you tried by creating this launch file and its configuration: link
Disclaimer: I have not tried this yet since I always use move_base in ROS1 to do the navigation. But I believe it is a good reference.

I actually tried it half an hour ago but I think I did it wrong by cloning the repo and running the launch file by "roslaunch costmap_2d example.launch" and I had an error: cannot launch node of type [costmap_2d/costmap_2d_markers]: Cannot locate node of type [costmap_2d_markers] in package [costmap_2d]. I then installed ros-noetic-navigation but this time I couldn't run "roslaunch costmap_2d example.launch". example.launch was not a launch file associated with costmap_2d

Another idea is still to use move_base node. You can borrow its features to produce the global_costmap, and remap its cmd_vel parameter to another topic. Then you publish your own navigation algorithm result to this cmd_vel topic.

Thanks, I got it to work for turtlebot3. Is there a way I can use it on a custom real life robot? I am using RPLiDAR.

Glad it works for you.
I think that question is for another topic that is unrelated to the original question. You should make another thread for this.
But to quickly answer your question: first, you need to define the URDF of this custom robot and make sure your transformation from your RPLidar frame to base_link frame exists. And the rest of it will be the same: load the robot model -> create the map -> navigation.
